# Удалить все сообщения из телеграм канала с помощью бота

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Есть канал телеграм в нем тысячи сообщений и удалять их вручную очень проблемно, можно ли как то с помощью бота на aiogram удалить вообще все сообщения из канала?

Comment: Даже если вы отслеживали все ID сообщений, сообщения старее 48часов удалить не получится. Clear history только если.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Так

```
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.utils import exceptions

# Вставьте ваш токен бота Telegram
bot = Bot(token="YOUR_TOKEN_HERE")

async def main():
    chat_id = -100123456789 # ID канала, из которого нужно удалить сообщения
    message_count = 0 # Счетчик удаленных сообщений

    async for message in bot.iter_history(chat_id):
        try:
            await bot.delete_message(chat_id, message.message_id)
            message_count += 1
        except exceptions.MessageCantBeDeleted:
            pass
    
    print(f"Удалено {message_count} сообщений из канала.")

asyncio.run(main())
```